# How to reactivate AdSense account?

Tags: google, google-adsense

My website was not approved on AdSense because of lack of content. Yes my mistake, but now I have added content and still do. But I can't find a way to resubmit the request to AdSense to be accepted and show Ads.
Please let me know what stepts should I take to activate Google AdSense?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The email you received when you you were rejected should have included these instructions for reapplying:

> To update and resubmit your application, please visit
>   http://www.google.com/adsense and sign in using the email address and
>   password you submitted with your application. Our specialists will review
>   your account for compliance with our program policies, so please make sure
>   to resolve all of the issues listed above before resubmitting.

Answer (score 1):

Attempts to correct the content that go against the rules, and then sends a request for revaluation in Google with [this form](https://www.google.com/adsense/support/bin/request.py?contact=appeal_form)

Comment: the form sais:"Please do not use this form if your account has never been an active AdSense account."  My account had admob, so don't know what to say about this.

Comment: The message I get in adsense is: "After reviewing your application for .......com, we're unable to accept you into the AdSense for Content program at this time."

Comment: I have submitted the form you suggested, but they replied that my account was never been active. So it's not the right form.
Do you have any other solution for resubmiting my application for adsense after I got rejected because of insufficient content? (now i added content on my website)

Comment: Argoment of your website ?

Comment: sorry Daniele, I don't understand what are you asking. You mean what is the website-address?